# How get user that is role in project that uses Identityserver4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, identityserver4

I have an asp.net core api project that I want use this api in my android Chat Application.This asp.net core Application uses Idenittyserver4 for registering users.I get the users that in one role like this:

**In IdentityServer4 application**

```
IList<AppUser> Supporters=await UserManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync("Supporter");
```

Now I in my asp.net core api How can I get users(for use as Contacts in Contcts List) that is one role like above?

**Asp.net core application that Uses IdentityServer4**

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
public async Task<IActionResult> Contacts()
{
    //How Can I get Users
    IList<AppUser> Supporters=await UserManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync("Supporter");
    return Ok();
}
```

**Edit**

I want to explain why I want to get Supporter users in above Asp.net core WebApi

I have several Asp.net core WebApi that I uses these in my android apps,in all of which I use my IdentityServer(that uses IdentityServer4) to register users with no problem.

Now there is another need in applications, for example in one application selling goods should define some users as users who support buyers, and in another application should define users as those who answer the question about our services.I Save two role in my identityserver , "SaleAppSupporter" and "ServiceAppSupporter", And I added users to these roles.

Now In each application I want to send these diffrent users to clients So they can see them on the contact list.

But I do not know how to solve this problem
Can any one can help me ?

**Edit 2**
Should I get user List from IdentityServer?

Comment: I think you cannot get userlist with a role,you can refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1?view=aspnetcore-5.0),there are no methods can do it.